# Grails g:ifLoggedIn tag not recognised

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

When the user successfully logs into the system i want to display the LOGOUT link. And if the user has not logged into the system i want to display LOGININ link.

It says that `<g:ifLoggedIn>` is not recognised.  I am using grails 2.2.4

```
<li class="dropdown" id="menuLogin"><g:ifLoggedIn>
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            id="navLogin">Login</a>
                    </g:ifLoggedIn> <g:ifNotLoggedIn>
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            id="navLogin">LOGOUT</a>
                    </g:ifNotLoggedIn>
```

Comment: If you're using spring-security-core then the tags use a different namespace and should be `<sec:ifLoggedIn>` etc.  If you're using a different security system please edit the question to indicate which one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tag if you use `spring-security-core` plugin

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn></sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

instead of

```
<g:ifLoggedIn></g:ifLoggedIn> // there is no such tag in g namespace
```